# How to compile a Jenkins workspace to a .jar

Tags: java, eclipse, git, jar, jenkins

I have a Jenkins hooked up with my Git. That works perfectly, it has .git, .settings, bin, src, .classpath, and .project in the job workspace. But what I wanted is, how do I compile all of this to a .jar and send it to a directory using SSH. The SSH part I know how to do, it's just the compiling I don't get. So this is what I want to happen: I build project > gets my git source on bitbucket.org > puts it on workspace > compiles to a .jar > grabs .jar and send it to SSH. 
Thank you. If you have any questions please ask!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a **build step** to your job to let Jenkins know how to build your project.
This could be ant, or maven, or really practically anything you can find a plug-in for.

You can even just have it invoke a shell script which contains the appropriate javac command, but I would recommend using a real build tool.

Comment: Okay, I'm on the Invoke Ant build step. What would I do from here to compile the workspace to a .jar?

Comment: Assuming you've got ant configured, you just need to point it at your build.xml.  Jenkins isn't doing anything fundamentally different than when you do it on your own box.

Comment: Sorry, I'm only 1 week old to Jenkins and I get everything except for the Compiling part. Could you show me an example of what this would look like? This is where I am currently: http://puu.sh/93Lpb.png

Comment: set build file to wherever your build.xml is. set targets to whatever target you have defined to do whatever kind of build you want.

Comment: I'm sorry... but I have no idea how to create an XML file to compile to a .jar.

Comment: Teaching you to use ant is well beyond the scope of a SO answer. You need to go google for some ant tutorials.

Comment: Thank you, your answer was right. I'm making it the answer because that was the answer, now I gotta learn how to use Ant. Thank you.